# how do I change the location of a Git repository

Tags: git

I'm completely new to using Git (and find it a lot harder to use than SVN already), and I noticed that the project I pulled in was dumped right in my C:/Users// directory. I prefer moving it somewhere else so how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just move the folder that contains all the source and the .git directory wherever you want.

Git doesn't tie the location of your clone to anything, it is only tied to the location of the upstream repository (the one that you cloned from, if your repository is a clone, that is).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can just move the directory (including the `.git` directory) with your favorite file management tool. In fact, if you don't need your working directory changes, you can just copy/move the `.git` directory and restore your files with `git reset --hard`.